# SQL Transaction Log best practices from a developer standpoint

Tags: sql-server

I am developing a system that should be deployed into on customers' on-premise SQL Servers. The system should then running unattended for years at a time and has a high database throughput (many inserts/deletes), which is communicated to the customers. Some seem to have their database configured "correctly" with regular backups or log truncates, others just let the transaction log grow until the disk is full.

When the disk is full, obviously not only my application, but also other unrelated systems using DBs on the same disk stop working.

Now, one could say it's the customer's fault, but you can't tell them that if you want them to use your system.

So, what can I, as the developer, do to tackle this problem? Should the system monitor the log growth, and send an email when the log spirals out of control? Should/could I monitor the SQL server disk space?

Of course I have a boldened **Attention** paragraph in the 12-page setup documentation regarding Log file growth, but no one seems to fully read them these days.

Comment: I presume switching to simple recovery model isn't an option?

Comment: @RogerWolf Not automatically without user notification, because the DBA may have chosen the recovery model for a certain reason.

Comment: if they have a DBA, then it's definitely not your problem. However, it might make sense to provide some UI to allow users to choose a "minimal footprint" mode (short data retention + simple recovery).

Answer (score 1):

> The system should then running unattended for years at a time and has a high database throughput (many inserts/deletes), which is communicated to the customers.

your database requires maintenance,at the least you should check for disk space,if you can't afford  any maintenance,then SQLAZURE may be best option for you,but this also still requires DBA

> So, what can I, as the developer, do to tackle this problem?

you should make them clear,its not what you support and this has to be dealt by them and ask them to hire a DBA

Log grows and it is inevitable for an OLTP System.if you are looking for best practices..below are few

1.Log files should be placed in seperate drive
2.Set Autogrowth in MB's not in percents

and check this link for more info on why this happens:[How best to maintain SQL log file sizes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40833/how-best-to-maintain-sql-log-file-sizes)

> Should the system monitor the log growth, and send an email when the log spirals out of control? Should/could I monitor the SQL server disk space?

you should monitor log growth.you could use below to monitor and send an email to alert when free space percent is less than 10

```
create table #t
(
dbname sysname,
logsize float,
logspaceused float,
status bit
)
insert into #t
exec ('
dbcc sqlperf(''logspace'')')
```

you could also check  mssql tips for advanced monitoring info:
[Monitor SQL Server Transaction Log File Free Space](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3617/monitor-sql-server-transaction-log-file-free-space/)

Comment: I can tell them to hire a DBA, but even if they don't listen, they will still think it's my fault that their SQL server crashes. So I guess when my application fails the fallout should be contained, it not take the whole SQL server with it.

Comment: if there is no space for tlog for a particular database,only it will be not available,but since it is placed in same disk as others(i assume),all will go down @Alexander